# Best way to implement a web-based application in android

Tags: android, web-applications, implementation

I'm developing an web-based application without PhoneGap.
The application consist on 7 modules (events, news, photos) and each module is one item on menu. Also each module is a independent webpage.
So, I don't know if I need implement 7 embedded browsers, or only one browser, or another kind of architecture.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to basically make an embedded browser that uses your website you should only have 1 browser.

If you are trying to have a better integration with the android platform you should create one activity that works as a web browser and pass the url inside the intent for each "module" you are trying to access.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Module". Is this something thats on the website or are you talking about activities inside the android platform?

Comment: In the old version of application, each module was an Activity, now each module is like a webpage of the application.

Comment: You should make one web browser object(the exact name escapes me) and then navigate using that. You can check to see when the user moves to a new webpage and then preform any necessary actions inside the app.